# The right column of a twocolumn document is infringing on the abstract

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am trying to write a class file for an upcoming collection of short papers by basically adding small changes to the article class. All papers will be set in the twocolumn format. In the class file, I have defined abstract and keyword environments to span across the two columns as

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
   \noindent\hskip15mm\begin{minipage}{16cm}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
   {\bfseries \abstractname :}}{\end{minipage} \end{@twocolumnfalse} \par}
```

and

```
\newenvironment{keywords}{\begin{@twocolumnfalse} \noindent\hskip15mm  \begin{minipage}{16cm}\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont {\bf Keywords:}}{\end{minipage} \end{@twocolumnfalse} \par}
```

But, after compilation, the right column of the subsequent text infringes on the abstract as well as keywords. I have also modified the \maketitle command but the text does not infringe on that. The effect is as shown below:
[image: The right column infringes on the abstract]

What should I do in the class file so that this does not happen?

Comment: you have put a 16cm minipage into one column which isn't that wide, so the outcome isn't unexpected. You can use `\twocolumn[spanning one-col material here]{ rest of document....` to put something full width

Comment: but that will have to be done in the document after begin{document}. i need to do something in the class file so that the text does not infringe on the abstract.

Comment: no look how article class does `\maketitle`  you can define the user command `\maketitle` or `\abstract` or whatever to do what is needed.